# Running react-native run-android shows "build failed with an exception"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-sdk-tools

Yesterday I could run android app perfectly but I don't know why, this morning I did react-native run-android like all days I work and it threw me BUILD FAILED with:

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
>   >     A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-device-info'.
>   >     Could not find runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0).
>   >         Searched in the following locations:
>   >             https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.jar

Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I have been searching solutions to the error but they doesn't works. One of the things I tried was this but with no solution:

> chmod 755 android/gradlew

I emphasize that yesterday was working normaly, is a project with so much time ago. I think could be something related with the sdk but I don't move very well with it. Someone know what could be? In IOS works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem  here today. I just clean gradle cache and got the same exception.

$ ./gradlew clean
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-device-info'.
  >   Could not find runtime.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0).
  >       Searched in the following locations:
  >           https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/runtime-1.0.0.jar

The file is missing here :https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.0.0/

// Update solution found here

Just set on project buikd.gradle :

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

**Before** the jcenter() and everything is OK.

```
allprojects { repositories { mavenLocal() maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } jcenter() maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" } } }
```

from https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/414

Comment: Yes I've reading it in react-native-device-info Github's site. I think that we will just have, to wait?
https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/413

Comment: https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/414#issuecomment-392491368 OK for me :)

Comment: pls, eddit your response like Github is to make your response the best!